# Winrt Scrollbar not working

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to use scrollbar (not scrollviewer) in window store application and it seems there is a bug. It doesn't display at all. It occupies the space as per set width but nothing else is visible.

I have set viewport,small change large change maximum etc but nothing working.(code below)

```
       <ScrollBar  Orientation="Horizontal"   ViewportSize="500" SmallChange="10" LargeChange="20" Maximum="1000" Minimum="20" Height="20" Margin="130,5,433,5" >

        </ScrollBar>
```

I can not use scroll viewer ,so need specific help on scrollbar only.

Please help. its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

See this article:

[In WinRT, How to use ScrollBar control as like in WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/69842a0e-6f1f-43eb-a49f-12b92094a61d)

The recommendation is that you use `ScrollViewer` for Windows Store App. What is your specific need in wanting to use `ScrollBar`?

Also, the article discusses the behaviour of `ScrollBar`, which might explain your issue.